# ROS 2: Message Filters (e.g. exact time)

Tags: ros2, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Potentially looking to move to ROS 2.0 for python 3 support in a new project.

Question I can't seem to find an answer too, is the feature of sync'ing messages working in ROS 2.0 yet? Is there an example of how to do this somewhere? Or another option of achieving the same function?

Rely on the message sync'ing pretty heavily for collating all our sensor data, without that ability upgrading to ROS 2.0 seems like a non-starter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318890/ros-2:-message-filters-(e.g.-exact-time)/) by [hwil292](https://answers.ros.org/users/29711/hwil292/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2019-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to `index.ros.org` the package `message_filters` has been ported: [index.ros.org/message_filters](https://index.ros.org/p/message_filters/github-ros2-message_filters/#crystal) and is available starting with the Crystal release.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1